# Received NaN in Reducer in Redux/React Js

Tags: redux

I'm trying to make a task which is every click will "INCREMENT" + 1 item number in the cart. But it does not work as expected and I got this error instead:

> index.js:1 Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.

My code is here

```js
const initialState = {
    counter : 0,
    cartData : []   
};

function cartNumber(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENT" :
      var index =  state.cartData.findIndex(el => el.name === action.newData.name);
      var cartNumber = Number(state.counter);
      if (index > -1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartData : state.cartData.map((el) => el.name === action.newData.name ? {...el, quantity : Number(el.quantity + 1), price : Number(el.price + el.total) } : el),
          counter : Number(state.cartData.map((el) => Number(el.quantity))) + 1 // NOTE : **I think this line is the error, but i dont know how to fix it**
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...state, counter : Number(cartNumber + 1),
          cartData : state.cartData.concat(action.newData) 
        }
      }
    break;
    case "DECREMENT" :
      if (state.cartData.quantity < 1) {
        return {
          ...state, 
          cartData : state.cartData.map((el) =>
            el.name === action.decrementData ? {...el, quantity: el.quantity !== 1 ? el.quantity - 1 : 1, price : el.price !== el.total ? el.price - el.total : el.price } : el)
        }               
      } else {
        return {
          ...state, 
          cartData : state.cartData.filter(el => el.name !== action.decrementData ),
          counter : state.cartData.map((el) => el.name === action.decrementData ? state.counter - el.quantity : el)
        }
      }
    default: 
      return state; 
  }
  return state
}
export default cartNumber;
```

I have been trying to fix it by convert all the quanlity to number but it still not working. It is originally a array because i took from the cartData array that is why i converted it.

Comment: It better to include a sample of `cartData`.

Comment: Here is it. [ { name : "string", quantity : 1 } ]      an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

`cartData.map` will return an `array`, you use `Number` and passing an `array` in. It will return `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

You might be right here:

```
counter : Number(state.cartData.map((el) => Number(el.quantity))) + 1 // NOTE : 
**I think this line is the error, but i dont know how to fix it**
```

The `state.cartData.map((el) => Number(el.quantity))` return an array. `Number([])` is 0, but `Number([any_item])` will return `NaN`